# How to convert jQuery removeClass into ReactJS way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the column with the id=`#golden-records-pane-address`, I would like to unhide the textboxes inside the same column. Ideally if I click somewhere else these text boxes shall be hidden again.  I have achieved the former by using  a piece of jQuery code.  I believe it would be cleaner to achieve this in ReactJS.  I understand how states are used, but unsure how to do it here.

```
var SearchResult = React.createClass({
render: function () {
       // The following shall be removed and turned into React
       $(document).on('click', '#golden-records-pane-address', function(){
            $('#golden-records-pane-address__inputs').removeClass('hidden');
        }); // End of jquery
     return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SUI</th>
                                ...
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {resultRows}
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr id="golden-records-pane">
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{this.state.site}</td>
                                <td id="golden-records-pane-address">
                                    {this.state.address}

                                    <div id="golden-records-pane-address__inputs" className="hidden">
                                        <input type="text" className="[ form-control ]" placeholder="Address line 1" />
                                        <input type="text" className="[ form-control ]" placeholder="Address line 2" />
                                        <input type="text" className="[ form-control ]" placeholder="City" />
                                        <input type="text" className="[ form-control ]" placeholder="Postcode" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>{this.state.country}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

What I have tried:

```
var SearchResult = React.createClass({
    onAddressClicked: function () {
        this.setState({
            show_address_details: true
        });
    },
render: function () {
    var cx_hidden = React.addons.classSet({
                    hidden: (this.state.show_address_details == true),
                    'form-inline': (true)
                });

return ( ...

    <td id="golden-records-pane-address" onclick={this.onAddressClicked.bind(this)}>
                                        {this.state.address}

                                        <div id="golden-records-pane-address__inputs" className={cx_hidden}>
                                            <input type="text" className="[ form-control ]" placeholder="Address line 1" />
                                            <input type="text" className="[ form-control ]" placeholder="Address line 2" />
                                            <input type="text" className="[ form-control ]" placeholder="City" />
                                            <input type="text" className="[ form-control ]" placeholder="Postcode" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
)
```

Comment: And what's wrong in your code? It looks fine. Only on `input` you should write `className="form-control"` without square brackes.

Comment: it shows the inputs right away. My click doesnt doesnt do anything.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Answer on it's way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state variable is a little confusing: you add `hidden` class when `show_address_details` is `true`. For me more intuitive would be comparing it to `false`.

Anyway mistake is that there is no initial state, which can be created by `getInitialState`:

```
var SearchResult = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { show_address_details: false };
    }
    …
});
```

Comment: Thats a good one. But it doesnt solve it. :( I have changed it additionally to `hidden: (this.state.show_address_details == false),`.   Now everything is hidden and click doesn't do anything. It seems the event doesn't get fired at all...

Comment: I found it. its `onClicked`, not `onclicked`.  Now how to solve the other part? How to hide them if the user clicks anywhere else?

Comment: My suggestion would be attaching click listener to body and checking if it's outside your react component. I have some draft version here: http://pastebin.com/HWvJ2a6x but haven't to go, so I can't finish working example.